# SauceLabs hybrid app test automation session is not starting on iOS devices

Tags: ios, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, saucelabs

I'm trying to run the automation tests for hybrid app on SauceLabs (SL) on Android and iOS. For some strange reason when I start execution on SL with iOS devices I can only see device with a spinner that is trying to start a session and it is going in loop for more than 20 min (that is how much I gave tests time to timeout last time I tried). For android devices is working perfectly fine and it finishes test execution. Some input about tools and environment:

1. Test frameworks: Appium, WebdriverIO, Cucumber.
2. Language: JS
3. Selectors used in code (Page objects): HTML custom selectors for each button/input field etc, from ionic (hybrid) app
4. In order to be able to access those selectors, in appium configuration file for SL I put following (`'appium:autoWebview': true`) which is suggested when you are dealing with hybrid apps. Checked with other projects that are working too (project that are using saucelabs with appium), config file is written in good format.
5. Artifacts used: .ipa app build for iOS (built properly, I was able to use it in manual testing), .apk for Android (all good there too).

Is there anything I'm missing to configure on my side to be able to run iOS tests on SL by using frameworks and locator/selector strategy I mentioned above? Or is it maybe some bug on their side that I missed to find? I spent few days researching this issue and couldn't find anything helpful besides official documentation which (I think) I followed in good way.

I'm sharing 3 config files I have for this (1 shared config, 1 iOS and 1 for Android):

1. Shared config

   ```
   const { generate } = require('multiple-cucumber-html-reporter');
   const { removeSync } = require('fs-extra');

   exports.config = {
   // ====================
   // Runner and framework
   // Configuration
   // ====================
   runner: 'local',
   framework: 'cucumber',
   sync: false,
   logLevel: 'trace',
   deprecationWarnings: true,
   outputDir: './test-report/output',
   bail: 0,
   baseUrl: 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com',
   waitforTimeout: 6000,
   connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
   connectionRetryCount: 3,
   specs: ['tests/features/**/*.feature'],
   reporters: [
       'spec',
       [
           'cucumberjs-json',
           {
               jsonFolder: '.tmp/json/',
               language: 'en',
           },
       ],
   ],
   cucumberOpts: {
       requireModule: ['@babel/register'],
       backtrace: false,
       compiler: [],
       dryRun: false,
       failFast: false,
       format: ['pretty'],
       colors: true,
       snippets: true,
       source: true,
       profile: [],
       strict: false,
       tags: [],
       timeout: 100000,
       ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false,
       tagExpression: 'not @skip',
   },

   // ====================
   // Appium Configuration
   // ====================
   services: ['appium'],
   appium: {
       // For options see
       // https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/packages/wdio-appium-service
       // If you need a logs from appium server, make log equal true.
       log: false,
       args: {
           // For arguments see
           // https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/packages/wdio-appium-service
       },
       command: 'appium',
   },

   port: 4723,
   // ====================
   // Some hooks
   // ====================
   /**
    * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
    * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
    * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
    */
   onPrepare: function() {
       // Remove the `.tmp/` folder that holds the json and report files
       removeSync('.tmp/');
   },
   /**
    * Gets executed after all workers have shut down and the process is about to exit.
    * An error thrown in the `onComplete` hook will result in the test run failing.
    * @param {Object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail
    * @param {Object} config wdio configuration object
    * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
    * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results
    */
   onComplete: () => {
       // Generate the report when it all tests are done
       generate({
           // Required
           // This part needs to be the same path where you store the JSON files
           // default = '.tmp/json/'
           jsonDir: '.tmp/json/',
           reportPath: '.tmp/report/',
           saveCollectedJSON: true,
       });
   },
   //This code is responsible for taking the screenshot in case of error and attaching it to the report
   afterStep(uri, feature, scenario) {
       if (scenario.error) {
           driver.takeScreenshot();
       }
   },

   afterScenario() {
       driver.reset();
   },

   afterSession() {
       driver.closeApp();
   },
   };
   ```
2. iOS SL config (I put stars to API keys for purpose of privacy):

   ```
   const { config } = require('../wdio.shared.conf');

   // ============
   // Specs
   // ============
   config.cucumberOpts.require = ['./tests/steps/**/app*.steps.js'];

   // ============
   // Capabilities
   // ============
       config.capabilities = [
       {
           deviceName: 'iPhone XR',
           // The reference to the app
           testobject_app_id: '1',
           testobject_api_key: '00768686F013470CB81060**********',
           // The name of the test for in the cloud
           testobject_test_name: 'IOS run',
           // Some default settings
           platformName: 'iOS',
           idleTimeout: 180,
           maxInstances: 6,
           // testobject_cache_device: true,
           noReset: true,
           orientation: 'PORTRAIT',
           newCommandTimeout: 180,
           phoneOnly: true,
           tabletOnly: false,
           autoWebview: true
       },
   ];

   // =========================
   // Sauce RDC specific config
   // =========================
   config.services = ['sauce'];
   config.region = 'eu';

   // This port was defined in the `wdio.shared.conf.js`
   delete config.port;

   exports.config = config;
   ```
3. Android SL config:

   ```
   const { config } = require('../wdio.shared.conf');

   // ============
   // Specs
   // ============
   config.cucumberOpts.require = ['./tests/steps/**/app*.steps.js'];

   // ============
   // Capabilities
   // ============
   config.capabilities = [
       {
           deviceName: 'Samsung Galaxy S9',
           // The reference to the app
           testobject_app_id: '1',
           testobject_api_key: '42724CEF3061453C9F45B1**********',
           // The name of the test for in the cloud
           testobject_test_name: 'Android run',
           // Some default settings
           platformName: 'Android',
           idleTimeout: 180,
           maxInstances: 6,
           testobject_cache_device: true,
           noReset: true,
           orientation: 'PORTRAIT',
           newCommandTimeout: 180,
           phoneOnly: true,
           tabletOnly: false,
           autoWebview: true
       },
   ];

   // =========================
   // Sauce RDC specific config
   // =========================
   config.services = ['sauce'];
   config.region = 'eu';
   // This port was defined in the `wdio.shared.conf.js`
   delete config.port;

   exports.config = config;
   ```

Appium Desktop caps:

```
{
 "platformName": "iOS",
 "platformVersion": "13",
 "deviceName": "iPhone 11 Pro",
 "app": "path-to-ipa"
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your conf.js files? Also, are you able to start a successful session from Appium Desktop to TestObject?

Comment: Hello @NikolayAdvolodkin , I added config code to the question. I was able to start successful session from Appium Desktop to TestObject. But when I try to run tests over there session is not starting on same iOS device :/ Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Try to keep it as simple as possible to start. Can you set only "platformName": "iOS" and "appiumVersion": "1.16.0". Remove deviceName, testobject_app_id, tabletOnly, noReset. Also, can you share your capabilities you used in Appium Desktop? @viktorija

Comment: According to documentation it seems that object id is mandatory https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Appium+Capabilities+for+Real+Device+Testing#AppiumCapabilitiesforRealDeviceTesting-RequiredCapabilitiesforRealDeviceTesting . Also for dynamic allocation of devices I'll need deviceName. For noReset and tabletOnly, I tried removing it and same result happened. :/

Comment: don't trust the docs, they get out of date. Check my tests here: https://github.com/saucelabs/sample-app-mobile/blob/hilton_tests/tests/e2e/spec/default/hilton.open.spec.js . Here's my iOS config: https://github.com/saucelabs/sample-app-mobile/blob/hilton_tests/tests/e2e/config/wdio.ios.rdc.conf.js . Feel free to pull it down and point it at your own app, it should work fine. Here's the whole branch https://github.com/saucelabs/sample-app-mobile/tree/hilton_tests